# Using premake with google test

Tags: c++, premake

I`m trying to implement premake to my first solution, all projects build fine except my googleTest project in Visual Studio 19 when I enter the test properties there is an additional property - "Referenced Packages" where Google Test is included. How to reference Google Test package in premake? My premake file looks like this

```
workspace "MyLib"
    configurations {"Debug", "Release"}

outputdir = "%{cfg.buildcfg}-%{cfg.system}-%{cfg.architecture}"
    project "MyLibTest"
        location "MyLibTest"
        kind "ConsoleApp"
        language "C++"

        targetdir("bin/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
        objdir("obj/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")

        pchheader "pch.h"
        pchsource "pch.cpp"

        includedirs {"MyLib"}
        links {"MyLib"}

        files{"%{prj.name}/**.h", "%{prj.name}/**.cpp"}

        cppdialect "C++17"
        systemversion "latest"
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay I got it, you can add packages by typing

```
nuget{"package:version"}
```